# Is there an efficient way of adding user_id using updateOrCreate?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to add/update responses from a multi-field form using updateOrCreate.

I'm avoiding having to write out the second argument in full for each field in the form by using `$request->all`.  However, this approach so far is precluding me from adding the value for user_id that is needed for the record to be complete.  That value (`$userId') is obtained in the controller as shown:

```
  $userId = Auth::user()->id;

  $cropid = $request->id;
  Crop::updateOrCreate(['id'=>$cropid],$request->all());
```

Is there a way of retaining the `$request->all` approach AND adding the user_id value?

Thanks, Tom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to generate an array with both data:

```
$data = array_merge($request->all(), ['user_id' => $userId]);
```

Then you can use the generated `$data` in your `updateOrCreate` method:

```
Crop::updateOrCreate(['id' => $cropId], $data);
```

Comment: That is exactly how I would do it